# Mysql update of results of select statements

Tags: mysql

I have two Joined select statements, which I want swap rank around. My joined select statement is:

```
SELECT l.id, r.id, l.rank, r.rank, l.oldurl, r.oldurl, l.newurl, r.newurl
    FROM (SELECT * FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE newurl REGEXP 'Itemid\=108' AND rank<>0 GROUP BY oldurl HAVING MAX(id)) AS l
        JOIN (SELECT * FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE rank=0 GROUP BY oldurl) AS r
            ON l.oldurl=r.oldurl;
```

I am trying to create an update statement, which would swap ranks around. Just to say that l.rank should become 0 in all cases in this case r.rank should become what is l.rank

```
UPDATE (SELECT id FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE rank=0 AND oldurl='zumba-gold-8.html' GROUP BY oldurl) r
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE newurl REGEXP 'Itemid\=108' AND rank<>0 AND oldurl='zumba-gold-8.html' GROUP BY oldurl HAVING MAX(id)) l
        ON l.oldurl=r.oldurl
            SET r.rank= l.rank, l.rank=0;
```

With this update statement I get that r and l tables can not be updated.

Comment: Your update query have prob. 
"SELECT id FROM as795_sh404sef_urls" This should be
"SELECT * FROM as795_sh404sef"_urls bcoz JOIN on "oldurl". And try your like "UPDATE r 

SET r.rank= l.rank, l.rank=0

using

(SELECT id FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE rank=0 AND oldurl='zumba-gold-8.html' GROUP BY oldurl) r JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE newurl REGEXP 'Itemid\=108' AND rank<>0 AND oldurl='zumba-gold-8.html' GROUP BY oldurl HAVING MAX(id)) l ON l.oldurl=r.oldurl ;

Comment: It is not working. Maybe there is another way. Basically I have one table, which update takes place as795_sh404sef_urls, but i need to swap ranking between two select closes. If first select brings rank 3, second one 1. I want that first start bringing 1 and second 3 and that would be the case for each row.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery. Maybe this will change in a furture version but not yet.